# Google Maps in UI TableView

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-markers, marker

Hi I'm new to Google maps in iOS.

may I know how to show marker in any location? That means when I click on a location on map it should show marker.

Thanks in Advance.

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86
                                                        longitude:151.20
                                                             zoom:6];
GMSMapView *mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
self.view = mapView;

// Creates a marker in the center of the map.
GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20);
marker.title = @"Sydney";
marker.snippet = @"Australia";
marker.map = mapView;

[mapView setSelectedMarker:marker];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please can you use delegate mathod of mapview
like :

-(void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:(id)marker 
{
    NSLog(@"yes"); // do something
}

and also check userinteractionenable for table view.